# C++ program error on passing arguments to the parameterized constructor by pointer object?

Tags: c++

I have a class called `sample`.

```
class sample
{
private:
    int Age;
public:
    sample() : Age() {}
    sample(int age)
    {
        this->Age = age;
    }
};
```

In main

```
int main()
{
    sample* s = new sample();
    s(21);

    return 0;
}
```

I want to pass values to the parameterized constructor through pointer object but it's giving this error

**expression preceding parentheses of apparent call must have (pointer-to-) function type**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've already constructed the object when did `new sample()`, so you can pass your constructor values right there. You cannot construct the object twice.

Do it like this:

```cpp
sample* s = new sample(21);
```

or

```cpp
sample* s;
s = new sample(21);
```

Comment: Or even: `sample s { 21 };`  There's no obvious need for a pointer here at all.

Comment: Its possible he requires a pointer for some subsequent use. Also, did you mean `s = sample{21}`?